# R - correlation matrix without duplicated values in edges

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, data-analysis

My data looks like

```
## data =
##  A B C a b c
##  0 1 0 1 1 0
##  0 0 1 1 0 0
##  1 1 0 0 1 0
##  0 0 1 0 0 1
##  0 1 0 1 1 0
##  1 0 0 0 1 0
```

How to correlate data for results like this:

```
##      A    B    C
## a   0.7 -0.2 -0.2 
## b   0.3 -0.5  1.0
## c  -0.7  0.4 -1.0
```

I'm inspired by this [article](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization), and I want to create similar heatmap. But more in this fashion:

[image]

Is running `cor(data)` and then cropping matrix to the desired submatrix is proper approach? Or I should run some other function rather than `cor(data)`?

Comment: Shouldn't the row names in your expected results be `a, b, c`?

Comment: They should - typo

Comment: `cor` can take two matrices / data.frames, so perhaps try `cor(d[c("a", "b", "c")], d[c("A", "B", "C")])` (or something less hardcoded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the desired submatrix is not a block from the diagonal of the whole matrix, I don't think there is some better shortcut and you should use

```
cor(M)[c("a", "b", "c"), c("A", "B", "C")]
#            A          B          C
# a -0.7071068  0.3333333  0.0000000
# b  0.5000000  0.7071068 -1.0000000
# c -0.3162278 -0.4472136  0.6324555
```

or just `cor(M)[4:6, 1:3]`.

Comment: Your answer and @Henrik `cor(d[c("a", "b", "c")], d[c("A", "B", "C")])` gives the same results. If I have large dataset is @Henrik answer more efficient?

Comment: @Everettss, yes, it should be. However, the dataset should be really large for there to be significant gains, since computing correlation isn't demanding. The efficiency gains would come from the fact that, given `k` variables, `cor(M)` computes `k(k+1)/2` correlation coefficients, and then you'd subset, say, `k^2/4` of them (if we split the set of variables in two halves, like in your example). So, the gains should be small for a large `k` and a moderate number of observations, and they should be higher in the opposite case.